# How to find a solution of $XA=AM$ s. t. $X$ is invertible.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations

Let $A$ be a complex $n\times m$ matrix ($n<m$), which is row full rank. For any $m\times m$ matrix $M$, such that $AM$ is still row full rank, can we find an invertible matrix $X$, such that $XA=AM$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** $A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$, and $M = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: Perhaps the downvoters could comment on their downvotes; the answer provides an example with $n = 1$, $m = 2$, where $A$ has full row rank, $AM$ also has full row rank, and where no $X$ with $XA = AM$ can exist.

Comment: You might have written what is now in the comment into the answer itself. But the example is crystal clear, +1.

Answer (score 0):

Some basic facts that can be used to reason about the problem:

- If $X$ is invertible, the rowspace of $XA$ is the rowspace of $A$.
- Every row of $AM$ is in the row space of $M$.

Comment: Can we characterize the matrices M which have corresponding invertible matrix X?